# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /misc/41/000/204/381/9/user/web/ragami.net/wp-settings.php on line 219

Tags: plugins, php

/**
 * WordPress Query object
 * @global object $wp_the_query
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
$wp_the_query =& new WP_Query();

how to skip this error ?

Comment: That's WordPress 3.1 or earlier. I guess you're trying to run a really old version on modern PHP? The [new version of this line](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.2.2/wp-settings.php#L409) is `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] = new WP_Query();` but you're bound to run into more problems. I know it's a risk too, but can you update WordPress to a newer version? Else your best option is probably to keep using the old PHP.

Comment: This msg appear 
"Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

Comment: This is still WordPress 3.1? [Old WordPress looks for mysql specifically whereas newer PHPs use mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44626316/243245). You can modify wp_check_php_mysql_versions (in wp-includes/load.php) to accept mysqli too - here's [the check in 5.2.2](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.2.2/wp-includes/load.php#L143) - or you can update to a newer WordPress that already knows about this.

Comment: thanks for your effort :)